# What does this statement in Java mean?

Tags: java

I am confused by this statement. Please help me explain this statement:

```
return third == Long.MIN_VALUE ? (int)first : (int)third;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your top tags in SO is Python, let's explain this statement with Python:

```
return first if third == sys.maxint else third
```

Of course the `Long.MIN_VALUE` is not necessarily equal to `sys.maxint` in Python.

Comment: that's no pyhton sir. But thank you for your help